# Any good suggestions for refactoring the following javascript code?

Tags: javascript, refactoring, polymer, frontend

Any ideas or suggestions for a more concise way to refactor this code?

Maybe a loop solution or something like that?

```
this._featuredImage = '../../../../../../../../content/images/' + this.post.slug + '.jpg';
this._checkImage(this._featuredImage, function() { // Image exists
  this.featuredImage = this._featuredImage;
}.bind(this), function() { // Image doesn't exist
  this._featuredImage = '../../../../../../../../content/images/' + this.post.slug + '.png';
  this._checkImage(this._featuredImage, function() { // Image exists
    this.featuredImage = this._featuredImage;
  }.bind(this), function() { // Image doesn't exist
    this._featuredImage = '../../../../../../../../content/images/' + this.post.datestamp + '.jpg';
    this._checkImage(this._featuredImage, function() { // Image exists
      this.featuredImage = this._featuredImage;
    }.bind(this), function() { // Image doesn't exist
      this._featuredImage = '../../../../../../../../content/images/' + this.post.datestamp + '.png';
      this._checkImage(this._featuredImage, function() { // Image exists
        this.featuredImage = this._featuredImage;
      }.bind(this), function() { // Image doesn't exist
        this.featuredImage = false;
      }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this));
  }.bind(this));
}.bind(this));
```

Thanks, I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Those folder paths are terrible `../../../../../../../../` lol. Instead `var imgPath = '../../../../../../../../content/images/'` then `this._featuredImage = imgPath + this.post.slug` and so forth.

Comment: This belongs on the code review stack exchange.

Comment: If you're going to post this on Code Review, you really have to explain what this code is doing, otherwise it will be down-voted and likely closed as unclear.

Comment: I didn't know people who write such code even exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start from changing hardcoded strings and code that is duplicated on first look:

```
this.setFeaturedImage = function(newImage) {

  this.featuredImage = newImage;
}

this.unsetFeatureImage = function() {
  this.featuredImage = false;
}

this.imagesRoot = '../../../../../../../../content/images/';
this.fileExtensions = ['jpg' => '.jpg', 'png' => '.png'];

this.getPostSlugImage = function(extension) {
    return this.imagesRoot + this.post.slug + fileExtensions[extension];
}

this.getPostDatestampImage = function(extension) {
    return this.imagesRoot + this.post.datestamp + fileExtensions[extension];
}
```

Than I changed anonymous functions calls to this objects methods. 
Here I saw that method call themselves on failure in chain. So I changed them to call unsetFeaturedImage on fail and returning false

```
this.trySetPostSlugJpgImage = function() {
  this._checkImage(this.getPostSlugImage('jpg'), this.setFeaturedImage(this.getPostSlugImage('jpg')).bind(this), unsetFeatureImage.bind(this));
  if(this.featuredImage == false) return false;
}

this.trySetPostSlugPngImage = function() {
  this._checkImage(this.getPostSlugImage('png'), this.setFeaturedImage(this.getPostSlugImage('png')).bind(this), unsetFeatureImage.bind(this));
  if(this.featuredImage == false) return false;
}

this.trySetPostDatestampJpgImage = function() {
  this._checkImage(this.getPostDatestampImage('jpg'), this.setFeaturedImage(this.getPostDatestampImage('jpg')).bind(this), unsetFeatureImage.bind(this));
  if(this.featuredImage == false) return false;
}

this.trySetPostDatestampPngImage = function() {
  this._checkImage(this.getPostDatestampImage('png'), this.setFeaturedImage(this.getPostDatestampImage('png')).bind(this), unsetFeatureImage.bind(this));
  if(this.featuredImage == false) return false;
}
```

And as a result I have:

```
if(!this.trySetPostSlugJpgImage())
  if(!this.trySetPostSlugPngImage())
    if(!this.trySetPostDatestampJpgImage())
      if(!this.trySetPostDatestampPngImage())
```

That we can close in function with simple name and use in our system

Comment: If `_checkImage` is async this won't work. But the question did not specify if _checkImage` is sync or async.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a loop of sorts, but because your `_checkImage` function is asynchronous, it can't literally be a `for` or `while`:

```
var images = [this.post.slug + '.jpg', this.post.slug + '.png', this.post.datestamp + '.jpg', this.post.datestamp + '.png'];
var index = 0;
setFeaturedImage(this);
function setFeaturedImage(t) {
    if (index < images.length) {
        t._featuredImage = '../../../../../../../../content/images/' + images[index];
        t._checkImage(t._featuredImage,
            function() { // Image exists
              t.featuredImage = t._featuredImage;
            },
            function() { // Image doesn't exist
              ++index;
              setFeaturedImage(t);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

I don't quite understand why you're saving the image being tested as `_featuredImage`. If that's not necessary, we can get rid of it:

```
var images = [this.post.slug + '.jpg', this.post.slug + '.png', this.post.datestamp + '.jpg', this.post.datestamp + '.png'];
var index = 0;
setFeaturedImage(this);
function setFeaturedImage(t) {
    if (index < images.length) {
        var image = '../../../../../../../../content/images/' + images[index];
        t._checkImage(image,
            function() { // Image exists
              t.featuredImage = image;
            },
            function() { // Image doesn't exist
              ++index;
              setFeaturedImage(t);
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Use recursion. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor and simplify your code by storing `this` in a variable instead of using `Function.prototype.bind`

```
var prefix = '../../../../../../../../content/images/';
var that = this;

function activateImageIfExists(image, elseCall)  {
    var fullImagePath = prefix + image;
    that._checkImage(fullImagePath , function() { that.featuredImage = fullImagePath; }, elseCall);
}

activateImageIfExists(that.post.slug + '.jpg', function() {
    activateImageIfExists(that.post.slug + '.png', function() {
        activateImageIfExists(that.post.datestamp + '.jpg', function() {
            activateImageIfExists(that.post.datestamp + '.png', function() {
                that.featuredImage = false;
            });
        });
    });
});
```

If you do not need to support old browser you can use arrow functions

```
var prefix = '../../../../../../../../content/images/';

var activateImageIfExists = (image, elseCall)  => {
    var fullImagePath = prefix + image;
    this._checkImage(fullImagePath, () =>  this.featuredImage = fullImagePath , elseCall);
}

activateImageIfExists(this.post.slug + '.jpg', () => 
activateImageIfExists(this.post.slug + '.png', () => 
activateImageIfExists(this.post.datestamp + '.jpg', () => 
activateImageIfExists(this.post.datestamp + '.png', () =>  this.featuredImage = false ))));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const path = '../../../../../../../../content/images/';
const images = [
    path + this.post.slug + '.jpg',
    path + this.post.slug + '.png',
    path + this.post.datestamp + '.jpg',
    path + this.post.datestamp + '.png',
];
const c1 = () => this.featuredImage = this._featuredImage;
const c2 = () => {
    let box = images.shift();
    this._featuredImage = box;
    this._checkImage(box, c1, box? c2 : () => {
        this.featuredImage = false;
    });
};

c2();
```